# How to return a single value with edge cases in Swift?

Tags: ios, macos, swift

Should I return a optional value like:

```
func someFunc(#num: Int) -> Obj? {
  if num < 0 {
    return nil
  }

  ...
}
```

Or just use `assert`:

```
func someFunc(#num: Int) -> Obj {
  assert(num >= 0, "Number should greater or equal then zero")

  ...
}
```

Edit: Now the conditions are identical in two cases, the number should greater or equal then 0. Negative values are not permitted.

Comment: @Zaph Sorry for missing the type. `num` is Int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use assert and the caller passes an invalid argument it is a non-recoverable error/crash. The caller may not be aware of all the ways the assert may be caused, that is internal logic the caller is not supposed to know.

Really the only time assert is meaningful is to check the calling arguments on method entry and even in that case it must be made clear to the user exactly what is invalid and that can never be made more stringent for the life of the method.

Since this is about Swift returning an Optional seems to make the most sense and it will be clear to the caller that a possible error must be handled. Optionals are a major feature of Swift, use them.

Or always return a useful result the way `atan()` handles being called with ±0 and ±Inf.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want the precondition of the function to be: if it is an error call it with a negative value (or non-positive; your two examples are contradictory), then go with the assert and document this. Then it becomes part of the contract that the user of the function must check the value if it's uncertain. Or if it makes more sense to support these values and return `nil` (e.g., the function will typically be called with such values and the `nil` is not an issue for that typical use), do that instead… Without knowing the details it's impossible to tell which suits best, but my guess would be the former.